# Mostrar datos que ingreso en el array JavaScript

Tags: javascript, array, lista

Tengo un problema en el cual no puedo mostrar los datos que añadi en el Array.
Quiero mostrar los datos en el apartado "Lista" pero no se como lograrlo ya que no se donde me quedan almacenados los datos para luego mostrarlos y que no se muestren solamente cuando los voy añadiendo.
Estuve intentando crear una nueva funcion que me muestre los valores pero no logro entender donde me quedan guardados asi puedo mostrarlos

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" name="text" id="inputText"> 
        <button onclick="pushData()">Añadir</button>
        <button onclick="mostrarValores()">Mostrar</button>

        <table border="1" ccellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <td>Nombre</td>
                <td>Lista</td>
               
            </tr>
            <tbody id="pText"></tbody>
        </table>


        <script>
            let users = [];

function pushData() {
    var inputText = document.getElementById('inputText').value;
    users.push(inputText);
    var pval = "";
   
    for(i=0; i<users.length; i++) {
        pval = pval +'<tr>'+'<td>'+users[i]+'</td>';
       
    }
    document.getElementById('pText').innerHTML = pval
}



        </script>

    
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let users = [];
```

Todas las rows (filas) de la tabla, están almacenadas en este array. Algo que noté, que te está faltando es cerrar el *<tr*>, y que las tablas se están re-asignando, y no agrupando.

```
pval += '<tr><td>'+users[i]+'</td></tr>';
```

También te saltaste el **<thead*>*

```
     <table border="1" ccellspacing="0">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Nombre</td>
            <td>Lista</td>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="pText">
       </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Con `pval += pval +'<tr>'+'<td>'+users[i]+'</td></tr>';` vas a duplicar contenido. Cambia `+=` por `=` o elimina `pval +` para solucionarlo.

Comment: Toda la razón, hay que eliminar el pval +